# How to isolate a URL from a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

I am taking a input message where a URL that leads to an image (ex : Hey check out this photo : https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/ZtV5K3UA1NBZx2HrP4-FrjGlbN713w7FTYdCfacgLZo/https/i.imgur.com/9ttsJot.jpg?width=431&height=498). I am then trying to take that message and isolate it to [the bold words] :  (ex : Hey check out this photo : **https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/ZtV5K3UA1NBZx2HrP4-FrjGlbN713w7FTYdCfacgLZo/https/i.imgur.com/9ttsJot.jpg?width=431&height=498**) so that I just have a pure URL.

I've found some code that checks to see if its a url :

```
if(new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?").test(Msg.content)){}
```

But I have no way to then take the message and isolate the URL from the rest of the Message.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Can you show an example of the text with the URL to make it clear what you're trying to achieve? Currently you have the same url twice which doesn't help the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string by spaces (with the user of [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) and use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get all words that match the URL regex:

```js
var regex = new RegExp('(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})');
function boldURLs(s){
  return s.split(" ").filter(e => regex.test(e));
}

console.log(boldURLs('Hey check out this photo : https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/ZtV5K3UA1NBZx2HrP4-FrjGlbN713w7FTYdCfacgLZo/https/i.imgur.com/9ttsJot.jpg?width=431&height=498'));
```

With multiple URLs:

```js
var regex = new RegExp('(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})');
function boldURLs(s){
  return s.split(" ").filter(e => regex.test(e));
}

console.log(boldURLs('Hey check out this photo : https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/ZtV5K3UA1NBZx2HrP4-FrjGlbN713w7FTYdCfacgLZo/https/i.imgur.com/9ttsJot.jpg?width=431&height=498 at https://discordapp.net'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.match(regex)`, you can get an array of all matching items (in this case URLs). From there you can utilize them directly or replace the original string...

```js
let str = document.querySelector('.content').innerText
let re = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?", "g");
let urls = str.match(re);
console.log(urls)

urls.forEach(u => {
  let isimg = false;
  let imgext = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png', '.bmp', '.webp'];
  imgext.forEach(i => {
    if (u.toLowerCase().includes(i)) isimg = true;
  });
  let t = isimg ? 'this image' : 'this link';
  str = str.replaceAll(u, `<a href="${u}">${t}</a>`)
});

document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = str
```

```html
<p class='content'>Hey check out https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/ZtV5K3UA1NBZx2HrP4-FrjGlbN713w7FTYdCfacgLZo/https/i.imgur.com/9ttsJot.jpg?width=431&height=498</p>
```